# How to invoke a React-router client side redirect to a new url in JS without using <Link>

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

here is a question for you regarding React-Router
What is the best practice when you want to invoke a client side redirect to a new url?
`<Link>` is nice, but I need to invoke a redirect inside a function in a given timing, so I want to invoke it in my JS script code and not in my jsx markup...
cheers
Ajar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using the methods `push` and `replace` from `browserHistory`.
Example:

```
// Repos.js
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'

// ...
  handleSubmit(event) {
    // ...
    const path = `/repos/${userName}/${repo}`
    browserHistory.push(path)
  },
// ...
```

Be aware that if you're not passing `browserHistory` to the `history` it wont work..
You should read the tutorial and the docs...
https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/12-navigating

https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/NavigatingOutsideOfComponents.md